# Python 3.8.0a3 failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding

Tags: cpython

When I call the embedded python from my c++ app, the application crashes. Something in `_PyCodec_Lookup` is not working. Debugging seems to indicate the error comes from this line in file `codecs.c`:

```
PyInterpreterState *interp = _PyInterpreterState_GET_UNSAFE();
if (interp->codec_search_path == NULL && _PyCodecRegistry_Init())
    goto onError;
```

`interp->codec_search_path` is NULL and `_PyCodecRegistry_Init()` returns -1.

This problems is already known; Solutions like removing python27, or setting environment variables `PYTHONPATH` or `PYTHONHOME` to either `""` or the src path  do not work.

I link to cpython version 3.8.0a3 which I've compiled with the included scripts inside the PCBUILD folder, using the same compiler as my applications (MSVC 15 2017).

The OS is windows 8.1 64 bit.

My application links to the produced binary python38.dll / python38.lib successfully but then crashes at runtime, and I have no idea what might cause the trouble - people suggest the environment is polluted, but it must not depend on the system's environment. How would I confidently ship the app to other people's computers? Did I maybe miss some compile flags or defines?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you are, but you are doing this after Py_Initialize ?

I include the python3.8 dll but when starting up I take the executable full
path and then add that to the python path (the code below is not tested but
it's roughly what I do)

```
void py_add_to_path (const char *path)
{
    PyObject *py_cur_path, *py_item;
    char *new_path;
    int wc_len, i;
    wchar_t *wc_new_path;
    char *item;

    new_path = strdup(path);
    py_cur_path = PySys_GetObject("path");

    for (i = 0; i < PyList_Size(py_cur_path); i++) {
        char *tmp = strappend(new_path, PATHSEP);
        myfree(new_path);
        new_path = tmp;

        py_item = PyList_GetItem(py_cur_path, i);

        if (!PyUnicode_Check(py_item)) {
            continue;
        }

        item = py_obj_to_str(py_item);
        if (!item) {
            continue;
        }

        tmp = strappend(new_path, item);
        free(new_path);
        new_path = tmp;
        free(item);
    }

    /* Convert to wide chars. */
    wc_len = sizeof(wchar_t) * (strlen(new_path) + 1);
    wc_new_path = (wchar_t *) malloc(wc_len, "wchar str");

    mbstowcs(wc_new_path, new_path, wc_len);
    PySys_SetPath(wc_new_path);
}
```

Comment: I'm also getting this error. I'm using Python 3.9, the current vcpkg version. 
The problem seems to be that it's looking for an encoding (for utf-8) and fails to find it in a given dictionary object ('interp->codec_search_cache' in 'codecs.c'). However, the only place I can see that this dictionary is added to appears to happen after this check. There is one item in the dictionary already but I think it's a dummy value (the objects aren't amenable to debugging, the contents aren't readable in the debugger).

Answer (score 0):

Seems a bit old now but looks like there is need to add the Lib folder including all the python system files to the search paths of the application.

Take a look at this Python port for [UWP](https://%5Bgithub.com/Greentwip/IronPython/tree/main/win8app/python34app%5D%5B1%5D)

It has an embedded python34app.zip that includes the codec files.